# How to compare three groups ranking a set of items?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ranking, group-differences, ranks

I have six photos which the test subjects rank according to their preference. So the response per person is six columns, "Rank of photo A" to "Rank of photo F".

I am grouping the subjects by religion, and I'd now like to compare the mean ranks of each picture per religion group.

What method would be useful to compare if the population groups defined by different religions rank the photos differently?

I was thinking about a MANOVA, but the fact that the last rank, the rank of photo F, is uniquely determined given all other ranks of one observation, might be a problem.

Edit: Four sample observations of the data look like this:

```
Rang.A Rang.B Rang.C Rang.D Rang.E Rang.F   religion
     6      4      2      5      1      3     muslim
     6      3      2      1      4      5  christian
     4      6      2      5      1      3  christian
     4      6      3      2      1      5   orthodox
```

Comment: please give your data in table form.

Comment: I added four sample observations in the main text. Is that okay?

Comment: It seems you have a largr number of data and and want to group it in three categories.  Anova could be useful option to test differences among three religions.